# Separate node apps or combined?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to plan out the best way to approach developing a node application, and am not sure what would provide the best performance. A little bit of info on the overall plan: the entire project will involve a web app as well as a 'bot' app. The bot app in question is node-steam, which is quite a substantial application on its own. My question is whether I should run two separate node processes for each app (one for web server and one for node-steam), or code them into one combined node process?

Also please note that I will need for the web app to be able to communicate with node-steam. I am planning on integrating socket.io into node-steam to make calls to it via web app actions. Is this the best approach if I keep the apps as separate node processes?

EDIT: When I refer to letting the web app communicating with node-steam, I meant that there are functions which need to be triggered in node-steam when a user does something in the web app (namely they perform specific actions in the browser), so I am planning on doing this via socket directly to the node-steam app, rather than to the web app and then routing the calls on to node-steam. As far as I can tell this is the simplest way of doing it.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I thought we should use Redis for multiple worker threads or multiple nodes? How do you intend to use socket.io for the 2 nodes communication?

Comment: Sorry I meant socket for letting the user communicate with the bot app via the browser, rather than having the web app communicate on the server with the bot app. I will edit my question to fix this

Answer (score 0):

If the bot app is quite substantial, you should code it for scalability. You probably will be spawning worker threads or even scale across multiple nodes in no time, for the bot app alone.